# Is there an open source solution to setup my own "CDN"?

Tags: nginx, server, cdn, vod

I currently have 1 dedicated server with 5TB of static content (mainly videos), It was holding up nicely with a small number of users but It seems like it can't keep up anymore.

I know a CDN is supposed to be in multiple locations but all I want is to setup more servers that sync files to the origin server and serve those files along with it.